# keep photo hidden after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have photos with a button to Hide/Show photo. what is needed is as follow:
If I press hide and refresh the page, the photo will remain hidden. I believe that is done by localStorage but I need help.

```
            int index=0;
            foreach (var item in Model.AttachmentsList)
            {

                <div style=" display: inline-block;">
                    @if (item.FileUrl.Contains(".jpg"))
                    {
                        
                        @Html.Raw("<a href='../../" + item.FileUrl + "' alt='img'> <img id='photo_" + index + "'  src='../../" + item.FileUrl + "'   > </a>")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.Raw("<a href='../../" + item.FileUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + item.FileName + "</a>")
                    }
                    
                </div>
                <button onclick="togglePhoto(@index)">Hide/Show Photo</button>
                index++;
            }
```

here is js:

```
<script>
function togglePhoto(index) {
    
    var photo = document.getElementById('photo_' + index);
    if (photo.style.display === 'none') {
        photo.style.display = 'block';
        
    } else {
        photo.style.display = 'none';
       
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the localStorage whenever a photo is toggled, and run a function `initPhotos` in

```html
<body onload="initPhotos()">
```

that hides the hidden photos whenever the page is (re-)loaded.

```js
function togglePhoto(index) {
  var hiddenPhotos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hiddenPhotos") || "{}");
  var photo = document.getElementById('photo_' + index);
  if (photo.style.display === 'none') {
    photo.style.display = 'block';
    delete hiddenPhotos[index];
  } else {
    photo.style.display = 'none';
    hiddenPhotos[index] = true;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("hiddenPhotos", JSON.stringify(hiddenPhotos));
}

function initPhotos() {
  var hiddenPhotos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hiddenPhotos") || "{}");
  for (var index in hiddenPhotos) {
    var photo = document.getElementById('photo_' + index);
    photo.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: I did as you said: <img id='photo_" + index + "'   onload='initPhotos()'> but it didn't work. what is wrong? @Heiko

Comment: The `onload` must be on the `<body>` element (only).